# How to perform StandardScaler on pandas dataframe with a column/columns containing numpy.ndarrays?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe that has some columns with numpy.ndarrays:

```
  col1         col2           col3         col4
0  4    array([34, 56, 234])   7     array([765, 654])
1  3    array([11, 598, 1])    89    array([34, 90])
```

And I would like to preform some type of scaling on.

I have done the pretty standard thing of:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

and I run into the pretty expected error of:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I need help standardizing these numpy arrays along with everything else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StandardScaler` expects each column to have **numeric** values but `col2` and `col4` have sequences and hence the error.

I think it would be best to treat columns with sequences separately and then combine back with rest of data.

For now, I will assume for all rows, no. of elements in sequence for a given column is same, e.g. all rows of `col_2` have 3 value array.

Since, `StandardScaler` calculates `mean` and `std` for all columns individually. There are two approaches for sequence columns:

#### Approach 1: Elements at all positions of sequence come from same distribution.

In this case, you should get `mean` and `std` over all values. After fitting `StandardScaler` on flattened array, reshape it back to original shape.

#### Approach 2: Elements at different position of sequence come from different distributions.

In this scenario, a single column can be converted to a 2D numpy array. You can fit `StandardScaler` on that 2D array (each column `mean` and `std` will be calculated separately) and bring it back to single column after transformation.

Below is code for both approaches:

```
# numeric columns should work as expected
X_train_1 = X_train[['col1', 'col3']]
X_test_1 = X_test[['col1', 'col3']]

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train_1 = sc.fit_transform(X_train_1)
X_test_1 = sc.transform(X_test_1)

# first convert seq column to a 2d array
X_train_col2 = np.vstack(X_train['col2'].values).astype(float)
X_test_col2 = np.vstack(X_test['col2'].values).astype(float)

# for sequence columns, there are two approaches:
# Approach 1
sc_col2 = StandardScaler()
X_train_2 = sc_col2.fit_transform(X_train_col2.flatten().reshape(-1, 1))
X_train_2 = X_train_2.reshape(X_train_col2.shape)

X_test_2 = sc_col2.transform(X_test_col2.flatten().reshape(-1, 1))
X_test_2 = X_test_2.reshape(X_test_col2.shape)


# Approach 2
sc_col2 = StandardScaler()
X_train_2 = sc_col2.fit_transform(X_train_col2)

X_test_2 = sc_col2.transform(X_test_col2)

# To assign back to dataframe, you can do following:
X_test["col2_scaled"] = X_test_2.tolist()

# To stack with other numpy arrays
X_train_scaled = np.hstack((X_train_1, X_train_2))
```

In approach 2, it is possible to stack all columns first and then perform `StandarScaler` on all of them in one shot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am about ready to implement this but I noticed that all my numbers are not in numpy types. Should I convert all these numbers in the arrays and integers in columns to their numpy equivalent type?

Comment: Yes! I would recommend that. I am editing my answer to convert everything to float before scaling!

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the array into a dataframe. My limited understanding is that it needs to work with 2-D arrays instead of a 1-D array.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

X = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([34, 56, 234]))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.array([11, 598, 1]))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)


from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

X_train
Out[38]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [-1.]])
```